# How to force background color + how to change icon for "pin to startup"

Tags: windows-phone-7

I tried to submit my first wp7 application but it got rejected because of area 7.1 what apparently is something to do with some icon that is used to be pinned.

I don't know if their is anything else that is wrong with my app(I thought I had all the requirements down) and that they just stop testing after the first thing they fail.

I know from reading online that there is something that users can change the background color of an app that causes alot of people to fail as well.

How can I force them to not be able to do this. I don't know how how to change the background color myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the icon that is used to be pinned the requirement is to disable this icon when item is pinned. You don't need to give user way to unpin icon from app, they can do that on main screen. So just check if item was already pinned and if yes, disable icon in application bar (I assume that you have it in application bar). You can check it using code:

```
((ApplicationBarIconButton)button).IsEnabled = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("?value=" + value)) == null ? true : false;
```

I don't quite understand second question but if you want your app to be fine with both white/black theme just set foreground colour for all items that you want to stay in one static color (like textblocks). If you will have it in XAML code, changing background theme will not affect your app.